# SOCAT command tailing from java app isn't working

Tags: java, linux, process, monitor, socat

Here is my `runCommand` that takes Linux command input as a string

```
    public static ArrayList<String> runCommand(String command) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            arrayList.add(line);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\nExited with error code : "+exitCode);
        System.out.println();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

It is working great with normal command like `ls` or `sudo lsof -t -i:132` or other. Even tailing live log from `ping google.com`. My `socat` command

```
sudo SOCAT_SOCKADDR=192.168.11.131 socat -d -d -T 10 UDP4-LISTEN:132,reuseaddr,fork UDP4:192.168.11.130:130,bind=192.168.11.131:133
```

(-d -d for verbose) in terminal creates socat process and tails the logs in terminals like incoming connection or connection status. but if I run this command via my `runCommand()`, this isn't printing anything in the terminal where the java jar application is running. And it worked fine for other cases of commands.

I tried placing the `process.waitFor()` before reading the loop but nothing. What is the problem here? my main goal is to parse the live-tailed log and do some other stuff depending on that.

Comment: It might well print to stderr. You're only processing stdout. I would seriously suggest you use `ProcessBuilder` too as it makes IO much easier for one thing

Comment: Thanks, process.getErrorStream() worked for me but can't think of the logic why the inputStream has been redirected to errorStream. And I didn't understand the advantage of using ProcessBuilder here?